# How to append div left side consecutively while the div reached at the bottom?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm developing the news feed by using jquery and php. I'm using 2 div for this.
Here If the main div reached at the bottom It should wrap automatically.

```
<html>
  <div id="main">
     <?php
     for($i=0;$i<15;$i++)
     {
     ?>
     <div id="sub">hai</div>
     <?php
     }
     ?>
  </div>
</html>
```

Script:

```
<script src="at/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var n = $("#main").css("height","100%");
if (n) {
    $("#sub").appendTo("#main");
}
});
</script>
```

Style:

```
<style>
#sub{
   border:solid 2px #000000;
   height:30%;
   width:20%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to make the column without using table? The column should contain 3 div only.

Comment: You could try to use a grid layout framework like [960 grid system](http://960.gs/) or [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which includes a 16-column grid. It's easy to get started and saves you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using CSS `clear:left;` and `float:left;` property.

Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2qLW/1/)**</kbd>

#### HTML

```
 <div id="main">
     <div id="sub">hai</div>
     <div id="sub">hai</div>
      <div id="sub">hai</div>
     <div id="sub">hai</div>
  </div>
```

#### CSS

```
#sub{
   border:solid 2px #000000;
   height:30%;
   width:20%;
   clear:left;
   float:left;
}
```

#### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var n = $("#main").css("height","100%");
if (n) {
    $("#sub").appendTo("#main");
}
});
```

---

Also you can solve dynamically assign css property,

Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2qLW/2/)**</kbd>

#### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var n = $("#main").css("height","100%");
    if (n) {
        $("#sub").appendTo("#main");
        $("#sub").css({
            border: "solid 2px #000000",
            height: "30%",
            width: "20%",
            clear: "left",
            float: "left"      
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The first column should have only 3 'sub' div. another 3 'sub' div will be in another column..

Comment: define #main width like 400px automatic next 3 element after come next line.

Comment: It doesn't work. In for loop first 3 divs in one column. And another 3 divs have to wrap into another column.

Answer (score -1):

Use [prependTo](https://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) jQuery function instead of appendTo